# Javascript validate form is not preventing submit

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I have a form and I do JavaScript validation function `onsubmit`:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this.id)" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='addjournalinfoform' style='border:0px;width:90%' class="formular" >
 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
        Journal
        </legend>
        <label>
            <span>* ISSN:</span><br />
            <input type='text' onfocusout="validateField('issn')" class='text-input' value="" name="issn" id="issn" style='width:30%'>
        </label>
   </fieldset>

</form>
```

and this is the function:

```
function validateForm(form)
{
    if(form=="addjournalinfoform")
    {
        alert('onSubmit');
        if($('#issn').val()=="")
        {
            $('#issnMsg').hide(500);
            $('#issnMsg .formErrorContent').html("* This field is required!<br />");
            $('#issnMsg').css('margin-left', $('#'+field).width()-20);
            $('#issnMsg').show(500);
            $('#issn').focus();
            $('html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)').animate({scrollTop: $('#issn').offset().top-50}, 0);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
        
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is even when the function returns false, the form is still submitted. What am doing wrong, and how to prevent the submit?

Comment: How do you trying to submit the form?

Comment: Submit using enter because there is no Submit button

Comment: -1 for using StackOverflow as a debugging tool

Comment: @bažmegakapa This question is ok.

Comment: @Stano Maybe I'm a bit strict, but people should not run to other people with every problem. On the other hand, I've helped him.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Yes you helped great! But many people even doesn't know that any Firebug exists and how to use it, then this is good place to ask for help. Nobody asked here `what have you tried?` So imho this question does not seem to be effortless. But once again, you gave him good advice and so also I can say: thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
$('#issnMsg').css('margin-left', $('#'+field).width()-20);
```

The variable `field` is not defined.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: field is not defined

**You must learn how to debug your own applications**, because you won't get far without it. Read about using the Console in whatever browser you are using.

You can find information about opening the console in your browser in [this Webmasters.SE question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: @HeshamSaeed One thing I don't get though. If you are already using jQuery, why not make use of the excellent event handling features jQuery has? Separation of concerns. Advanced event handling model. Would be much better than the old inline event handling.

Comment: I'm new to jQuery, I know native javascript well. for now I will do the hard things with jQuery only, in future will write pure jQuery. Thanks tho

Comment: @HeshamSaeed Good luck on your journey with jQuery. Only advised because event handling is one of the strongest parts of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

open console (firebug, chrome, opera, ie9 have that).
Check if there is no errors while executing validateForm().

I guess is there error in line:

```
 $('#issnMsg').css('margin-left', $('#'+field).width()-20);
```

There is an error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: field is not defined
```

Do you have declared `field` variable?

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to look at the debug console. It can make things so much clearer...